# Android Классы в отдельном файле

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В общем, не так давно начал разрабатывать под Android, и в тестовом приложении скопилось очень много кода. Можно ли выносить в файлы классы от одного Activity, а то стало сложно ориентироваться? И если возможно, желательно с небольшой пошаговой инструкций.

Comment: Просто разнесите функционал по отдельным классам. Однотипные, например диалоги или модели, кладите в отдельные папки. В любом случае ответ "можно" )

Comment: @kulikovman Окей, а инструкцию можно?? А то я щас попытался в итоге получил много разных ошибок. По этому как-то не особо убедительно.

Comment: как насчет принципа SOLID, конкретно буквы S? Не можно, а нужно. Сваливать весь код в контроллер (активити) ни к чему хорошему не приведет

Comment: @pavlofff Я прочитал про SOLID, да все круто теперь как мне создать правильно файлы с такими классами?? Потому что если я не пишу метод OnCreate в создаваемом классе, android studio начинает ругаться ((

Comment: в активити должно быть только то, что относится непосредственно к контроллеру виджетов (чем и является активити) - реакция на взаимодействие с интерфейсом, изменение вида  и тп. Все остальное выносится в отдельные классы и вызывается по мере надобности. Что, к примеру делает это ваше "очень много кода"?

Answer (score 0):

Можно.Только те куски кода в которых нет обращения к `контексту`.А то по моему придется унаследоваться от Application или еще что то делать..

Comment: Можно просто передавать Context в аргументах

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев если много обращений к контексту , шансов попасть на утечки повысятся ?нет? Меня самого очень интересует этот вопрос.если да как этого можно избежать?.из за этого я разделял логику на множесво активити.